# How can I create router and load balance service added to traefik via consulCatalog?

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik, consul

I have nextcloud running on bare metal 2 nodes:

```
node1: 192.168.1.10
node2: 192.168.1.11
```

In the consul I have defined nextcloud service as such on both the nodes:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "nextcloud",
    "tags": ["nextcloud", "traefik"],
    "port": 80,
    "check": {
      "tcp": "localhost:80",
      "args": ["ping", "-c1", "127.0.0.1"], 
      "interval": "10s",
      "status": "passing",
      "success_before_passing": 3,
      "failures_before_critical": 3
    }
  }
```

now this shows up in consul fine:
[image]

static config: `traefik.yaml`

```
global:
  # Send anonymous usage data
  sendAnonymousUsage: true

api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true

log:
  level: DEBUG

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: "/config/"
    watch: true
  consulCatalog:
    defaultRule: "Host(`{{ .Name }}.sub.mydomain.com`)"
    endpoint:
      address: http://127.0.0.1:8500

certificatesResolvers:
  linode:
    acme:
      caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      email: myemail@domain.com
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: linode
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"
```

and then dynamic `/config/config.yaml`:

```
http:
  routers:
    nextcloud@consulCatalog:
      entryPoints:
        - "https"
      rule: "Host(`home.sub.mydomain.com`) && Path(`/nextcloud`)"
      tls:
        certResolver: linode
      service: nextcloud

  services:
    nextcloud:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://192.168.1.10
          - url: http://192.168.1.11
        passHostHeader: true
```

but this shows up as file provider with TLS in instead in addtion to exisiting consulcatalog provider.

[image]
and not IP or domain mapped.

actual consulcatalog provider showing up but no tls
[image]

I am wondering why my dynamic configuration in http did not updated the nextcloud@consulcatalog and set the https entrypoint.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am struggling very hard to get this to work.
I have tried following the docs on traefik but its very confusing specially on the consulcatalog part.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is showing up as being defined via the file provider because you are statically defining it in the file at `/config/config.yaml`.

In order to dynamically retrieve this configuration from Consul, you should not be defining the static config file and instead configure tags on the Consul service registrations that will instruct Traefik to route traffic to your service.

For example:

```json
{
  "service": {
    "name": "nextcloud",
    "tags": [
      "nextcloud",
      "traefik.enable=true",
      "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.entrypoints=https",
      "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.rule=(Host(`home.sub.mydomain.com`) && Path(`/nextcloud`))",
      "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.tls.certresolver=linode",
      "traefik.http.services.nextcloud.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"
    ],
    "port": 80,
    "check": {
      "tcp": "localhost:80",
      "args": [
        "ping",
        "-c1",
        "127.0.0.1"
      ],
      "interval": "10s",
      "status": "passing",
      "success_before_passing": 3,
      "failures_before_critical": 3
    }
  }
}
```

More info can be found on the [Routing Configuration](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/consul-catalog/) docs for Traffic's Consul catalog provider.